# isnull values not in the table to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

TableA contains data from id's 55,66,68,70.

My Query:

```
select id, count(id) as total from TableA where id in (10,22,43,55,66) group by id
```

Output:

```
id       total
55       2
66       5
```

Desired Output:

```
id       total
10       0
22       0
43       0
55       2
66       5
```

Is there a way I can rewrite this query and have an isnull to 0 for the values in the IN statement that are not in the table?  For example, 10,22, and 43 are not in tableA but are in the IN statement, so I want the total for those values to be 0

UPDATE:  I forgot to mention the values from the IN statement are passed to the query as in array from the client application.  So the values are constantly different so I cant hard code anything

Comment: What do 10, 22, and 43 represent?  I'd recommend going about this in a different way, should there be a join to the table that sources these ids?  If 10, 22, and 43 don't exist in the database, this is expected behavior, while you can work around it, it'd be easier to handle it in application layer.

Comment: @Devon I updated my question with more info.  The values are passed as an array from the client so they are constantly changing so I can't hard code anything

Comment: Well, like I said, it'd be easier and most likely more efficient to handle it in the application layer then, not SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE a Table Variable and then use that

```
DECLARE @Ids TABLE (id int, PRIMARY KEY(id))
INSERT @Ids(id) VALUES (10),(22),(43),(55),(66)

SELECT i.id, ISNULL(COUNT(id),0)
FROM @ids i 
LEFT JOIN TableA ta ON ta.id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with `in`.  You can do this with a `left join`:

```
select t.id, count(a.id)
from (select 10 as id union all select 22 union all select 43 union all
      select 55 union all select 66
     ) t left join
     tableA a
     on a.id = t.id
group by t.id;
```

Comment: the values from my IN statement are from an array passed from the client.  So I can't hardcode all the unions.  There can be 5 values or 100 values in the array

Comment: @SlopTonio so generate the inner query. This answer does not imply you should have anything hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

If your ID's are within a reasonable range then you can create a recursive call to build a table containing all possible id values and the IN clause will filter it down to only the values you want. Then join that result set with the original table to get your count:

```
WITH AllNumbers AS (
    SELECT 0 AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x+1 FROM AllNumbers WHERE x < 100
) 

SELECT an.x, COUNT(id)
FROM 
    TableA ta
    RIGHT JOIN AllNumbers an ON ta.id = an.x
WHERE an.x IN (10,22,43,55,66)
GROUP BY an.x
OPTION (maxrecursion 100)
```

You can adjust the '100' values to a higher number but it creates a call stack within SQL that will hit a limit at some point.

Alternatively, if you have an existing table that contains all possible ids then join to that instead of 'AllNumbers' and eliminate the recursion.

Otherwise there may be some regex options to pivot the set into rows and then use the same join statement above.